# long duration post request by axios get empty response and network error

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, axios

I'm using react js for  the frontend, and node js for backend. I have few many post service in express and can get the result when my computation time in post service is less than 3 minutes but in cases with more than 3 or 4 minutes axios return the network error and empty result. all of services in postman works. i increase the request timeout in axios request but the problem not solved yet.

```js
axios.defaults.timeout = 5000000;
const damageMap=await axios.post("/api/damage",object,{timeout: 5000000});
```

Comment: I think there is a somewhere in your express server a timeout limit, maybe might worth to look for that. You can set your own servertimeout: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/http.html#http_server_settimeout_msecs_callback

Comment: express js has a default timeout of 2min. You need to increase that